# Need help to write a similar codes to these in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES;

SELECT Count(*) as osszIndex 
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE lower(object_type) = 'index';

SELECT text 
FROM DBA_VIEWS 
WHERE upper(view_name) = 'NEZETPL' 
AND upper(owner) = 'GI17_SAJATNEPTUN';
```

or similar to this one

```
SELECT *
FROM DICTIONARY
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ’%INDEX%’;  

DESCRIBE USER_INDEXES  ;

SELECT INDEX_NAME, TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_INDEXES  ;
```

Comment: This is a list of queries against Oracle data dictionary views. What is your question?

Comment: We need a specific question.

Comment: I need to write a query with some other Oracle data dictionary views. You can probably guess but i'm not quite versed in this topic, but i need to write something viable with this kind of method...

Comment: I wish i could be more specific but my prof only gave us these queries to write something similar to this.

Comment: The Oracle Reference guide contains a list of all the Data Dictionary views. Knock yourself out. [Link to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/nav/catalog_views.htm).

Comment: You need to be specific with your request.  What you have here is viable to run on Oracle (with the exception of "describe user_indexes" which isn't an sql command but is a valid command for sqlplus).  So even if this is YOUR HOMEWORK, there should be some more specific guidelines.

Comment: I wish i could be more specific. Damn if it would be more clear i wouldn't even post it in the first place. There are no guidlines, specifications, nothing! The only lead i have is that we have is that, we have to write a working query with these kinds of dictionary views.